# Implement File_gets_contents() and image

Tags: php, web

I want to write a php program, that will take get the images also, the problem is when i do file_get_contents, i only get html excluding the images.How can i go about?

Comment: you question is very vague. get images from where? what are you using file_get_contents() on? what do you mean by "i only get HTML"? overall, what are you trying to accomplish? from your question I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents reads the contents of the file and not the contents of the linked files. your script should provide functionality for retrieving the linked files on detecting the links in file being read

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a posix environment, you might want to consider invoking wget recursively through shell_exec and let wget do the heavy lifting for you.  There's an [article](https://superuser.com/questions/264446/using-wget-to-recursively-crawl-a-site-and-download-images) about it on superuser.com.